# Storeasync() is giving exception in windows 8 but working fine in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, exception, bluetooth

```
StreamSocket socket = null;
DataWriter datawriter = null;
DataReader dataReader = null;
socket = new StreamSocket();
datawriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);  

public async Task<byte[]> sendreceive(byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        datawriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
        await datawriter.StoreAsync(); //Exception here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

//connect the socket
socket = new StreamSocket();
await socket.ConnectAsync(
    rfcommService.ConnectionHostName, 
    rfcommService.ConnectionServiceName,
    SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
```

The exception comes is: `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in filename.exe`

`Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)`

Please help if anyone can.

Comment: Problem isn't caused by the code you posted. How are you creating your DataWriter? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: StreamSocket socket = null;
DataWriter datawriter = null;
DataReader dataReader = null;

       
            

socket = new StreamSocket();
datawriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

Comment: You can edit your question to include that. Did you [connect your Socket?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx#create_the_streamsocket_and_connect_to_the_server)

Comment: yes....i connected the socket

Comment: i have edited my question and included the code there.

Comment: I've formatted your code; please use an IDE to format before you add to your question, then indent by 4 spaces so stackoverflow does syntax highlighting. Your code as stands does not compile - please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. Often, trying to do this will reveal the problem.